# struts2 token Session for normal action not form

Tags: java, struts2, interceptor

I'm trying to use the `<interceptor-ref name="tokenSession"/>` in all actions. even the one that are just a result of redirection, and not only for forms submit. Is it possible?

Comment: And also, i have action that execute form using jquery and json, how can i declare interceptor there?

Comment: Interceptors doing their job on action invocation and it doesn't care what action is. But you should construct a stack to be used for every action if you need so.

Comment: What would it mean for a form-less action to have a token? How would the token be represented? You might want to consider creating your own token interceptor, but you'd need to differentiate between requests that have no token that *should* have one, and requests with no token that don't *need* one. Seems fishy to me.